# XML - Elements not outputting in desired order

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to change the order that the elements are outputted in. It currently displays them like this: "Maths:English:Science:ABA (GCSE);(GCSE);(GCSE);"
I need a way of ordering it so that I can display it like this:
"Maths:A (GCSE); English:B (GCSE); Science:A (GCSE);"
I am a novice with XML so please try not to show any overcomplicated solutions if possible!

XSL Code:

```
<xsl:template match="education">
<div style="float:left;">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="qualifications/qual"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="qualifications/grade"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="qualifications/level"/>
</div>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="qual"><span style="color:grey; font-size:15px; font-family:verdana;">        
<xsl:value-of select="."/></span><p1>:</p1></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="grade"><span style="color:grey; font-size:15px; font-family:verdana;"><xsl:value-of select="."/></span><p1> </p1></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="level"><p1> (</p1><span style="color:grey; font-size:15px; font-family:verdana;"><xsl:value-of select="."/></span><p1>);</p1></xsl:template>
```

XML Code:

```
<qualifications>
            <qual>Mathematics</qual>                        <grade>A</grade>    <level>GCSE</level>
            <qual>English</qual>                            <grade>B</grade>    <level>GCSE</level>
            <qual>Science</qual>                            <grade>A</grade>    <level>GCSE</level>
</qualifications>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're first applying templates to all the `qual` children, then each `grade`, then each `level` and getting exactly the output you should expect from that. Instead, simply process the children in order inside your `education` template:

```
<xsl:template match="education">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="qualifications/*" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

This applies templates to all children of `qualifications` in document order (i.e. the order they appear in the document). There is no need to loop or select particular siblings. Let the XSLT processor do the work for you.

Comment: I can happily report that this method also works; and (as you've stated) uses much less code, as the XSLT processor is taking care of it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This should do. looping on each qual, storing position in a variable and applying templates to elements in order:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="education">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <xsl:for-each select="qualifications/qual">
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../qual[$pos]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../grade[$pos]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../level[$pos]"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="qual"><span style="color:grey; font-size:15px; font-family:verdana;">        
<xsl:value-of select="."/></span><p1>:</p1></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="grade"><span style="color:grey; font-size:15px; font-family:verdana;"><xsl:value-of select="."/></span><p1> </p1></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="level"><p1> (</p1><span style="color:grey; font-size:15px; font-family:verdana;"><xsl:value-of select="."/></span><p1>);</p1></xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks very much (especially for the quick response!) - This method works a treat. Thanks for explaining how it works too.

Comment: Just a note, it's rarely necessary to use `for-each` in XSLT and this is a case where it's not really recommended. The XSLT processor *already* visits elements in document order. You don't need to do it explicitly.

Comment: @lwburk, nice.. its really that simple :)